# skip lines in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm very new to Python and we are using pandas to read a text file and retrieve data from specific lines.

There are 44 lines listed in my text file but I only need from line 35 -44.  And I need to exclude everything but "President", "Took office", "Left Office", "Party".  I have this function but its not reading my df1 that will be my dataframe.

```
def party_list():
    df1 = pd.read_table("presidents.txt", delimiter=",",usecols=["President ", "Took office ","Left office ", "Party "])
    location1=r' /users/Paula/PycharmProjects/Spring 2018_Paula/ '
f = open("presidents.txt",'r')
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if line == "":
        break
    print(line)
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: I think maybe you should call `party_list()`? Also `party_list` doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the first N rows via the `skiprows` argument of the constructor:

```
df1 = pd.read_table(
    "presidents.txt",
    delimiter=',',
    usecols=["President ", "Took office ","Left office ", "Party "],
    skiprows=34
)
```

You can also read the entire dataframe, then take just the last N rows via `.tail(10)`:

```
df1 = pd.read_table("presidents.txt", delimiter=",",usecols=["President ", "Took office ","Left office ", "Party "])
df1 = df1.tail(10)  ## 10 is actually the default amount
```

There are several other ways to do this as well :)

Comment: Thank you that worked. Now I have a csv file with data and a txt file with data that I need to read information from both. In particular I need the total from "Annual" column in csv and "Party" from txt file. I'm confused how to do this using pandas in Python.

Comment: If you found an answer helpful, feel free to accept it.  If you have additional questions, you can post it as another question